# JavaScript New Date()

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code but for some reason time is not including minutes:

```
var austDay = $("#<%= hiddenFieldTime.ClientID %>").val().split(" ");

var year = austDay[0];

var months = austDay[1];

var days = austDay[2];

var time = austDay[3];

var timeUntil = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(months), 
                         parseInt(days), parseInt(time));
```

When I debug using firebug these are my value:

```
$("#ctl00_hiddenFieldTime").val() = "2011, 5, 6, 14:20:00"

year = "2011,"

months = "5,"

days = "6,"

time = "14:20:00"

timeUntil = Date {Mon Jun 06 2011 14:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
```

As you can see, timeUntil is set to `14:00:00` instead of `14:20:00`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`parseInt(time)` is the problem

Here are the few dates initialization format

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 17):

According to the [Mozilla documentation for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), the following constructors are supported:

```
new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])
```

This means that in your constructor, when you pass `parseInt(time)`, that parameter is only used for the `hour` parameter. You need to pass a separate parameter for minutes, and yet another one if you happen to want seconds.

---

Also, you should always pass a `base` parameter to `parseInt`, like so:

```
parseInt(hours, 10)
```

Otherwise when you go to parse a value with a leading `0` such as `parseInt('08')`, the value will be interpreted as an octal number.

Comment: Where dateString should be in a format recognized by [the parse method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Answer (score 3):

Your last conversion is going to drop everything after the colon:

```
parseInt("14:20:00"); // 14
```

The whole conversion is rather bloated, I suggest trying to format the string initially in a format you can pass *as is* to JS's `Date` constructor, which will make life easier.

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt ("14:20:00")` returns 14